# ConvertAvroToJSON Apache Nifi with data type preserve

Tags: json, apache-nifi, avro, converters

Below is the flow that I've created to fetch data from DB and invoke a web service.

QueryDatabaseTableRecord --> SplitAvro --> ConvertAvroToJson --> EvaluateJsonPath --> ReplaceText --> InvokeHTTP

While converting AvroToJson, the date column is being interpreted as an integer value.

Date format from DB within avor object
[image]

Date format has converted to integer after converting Avro to Json.
[image]

Is there any way of preserving the data type while converting Avro to Json?

Avro schema that I've tried:

```
{
  "type" : "myschema",
  "namespace" : "nifi",
  "name" : "result",
  "fields" : [
     { "name" : "ID" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "IDEXT" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Copany" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Title" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Name" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Name1" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Name2" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Name3" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Name4" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Alais" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Legacyid" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Language" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Searchterm1" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Searchterm2" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Effectivedate" , "type" : "timestamp" },
     { "name" : "Recon_account" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "SortKey" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "CashMgmtGroup" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "ValueAdjust" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "LegalStatus" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Attr1" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Attr2" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Comments" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Vendor" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Authorization" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "TradingPartner" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "CheckDigit" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Industry" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "TrainStation" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "Contains" , "type" : "string" },
     { "name" : "RepublishFuncion" , "type" : "string" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please edit the post with your avro schema you used in ConvertAvroToJson

Comment: I've not used any Avro schema initially. Later I've tried with the above schema. But that didn't work as well.

Comment: Leave it as string not timestamp.  A date is not a timestamp.   If you need to work on that value to get a real timestamp from the date,  for example to figure out "tomorrow" from the date, you will want to use the string, and then use expression languages for timestamps....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ramu Convert the field as a string, not a timestamp as a date is not a timestamp.

If you need to work on that value to get a real timestamp from the date you will want to use the string, and then use expression languages for timestamps.   You would do this in updateAttribute on attributes you have extracted via EvaluateJson.

An example to a full timestamp is:

```
${dateString:toDate("yyyy-mm-dd"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

An example for yesterday is:

```
${dateString:toDate("yyyy-mm-dd"):toNumber():minus(86400000):format("yyyy-mm-dd")}
```

Notice you tell it the format of the string in toDate, then can chain functions together, and finally tell it the output format.

You can find some other examples of working with timestamps in my nifi templates:

https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates/blob/master/Working_with_TimeStamps.xml